# Pokemon require less candy to evolve?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have heard that the most recent change allows one to evolve some Pokemon with less candy than before. Is this true, and, if so, which Pokemon can now be evolved with less candy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zubat and Horsea both now only needs 25 candies to evolve instead of 50. This is likely because second evolutions were added to Pokemon Go as part of the Johto region Pokemon (second generation Pokemon).

Zubat + 25Candy = Golbat; Golbat +100C = Crobat

Horsea +25C = Seadra; Seadra + 100C = Kingdra